# How to make pandas bar chart starting from 0?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"hour": range(4,24,1), 
                   "rate": np.random.random(size = len(range(4,24,1)))
                  }, columns = ["hour", "rate"]).set_index("hour")
```

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (12, 8))

df.plot(kind = "bar", xlim = (0,24), ax = ax);
```

[image]

Need to have a bar for each hour, but xticks labels only aligns with the index.

Comment: What is the issue ? Just add hours to have from 0 to 24h ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the other values to the index?

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([0]*4, columns=['rate']), df])
df.index.name = 'hour'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (12, 8))
df.plot(kind = "bar", xlim = (0,24), ax=ax)
```

[image]